# how to set default text for new document in notepad++ editor?

Tags: notepad++

I am successful in setting default language as java in Notepad++, but not in setting default code. so someone please suggest me about how to set this code as default code, when ever I create a new document.

The default code to be auto generated is:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String line;
       while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PlugIn **NewFileBrowser** for that purpose. It comes with some defaults and enables you to create your own templates.

It's available via the Plugin Manager.
For more details refer to [this tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-custom-file-templates-for-programming-in-notepad-plugin/).

## Edit:

You can **edit the intial text** of the template via the plugin's *option* menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,
It works fine but again have a problem, here by clicking cntrl+alt+shift+n a new document is generated with default code but it was saved with a default name, i dont want this and I also want to change the templet. so is it possible to do this?

Comment: For the body of the template see my edited answer. What do you mean with your other question? The default name?

Comment: default name is when i press cntrl+s document is saved with some automatic name,
any way, from now i will use cntrl+alt+s i.e save as to save .
Ok fine, now problem was solved thank you so much for your suggestion :)